# Can't access Edit button for custom JIRA field, due to HTML tag in field description

Tags: html, jira, jira-rest-api

In our JIRA instance, someone thought that because you could put html tags in description fields, that meant that you needed a full complement of tags to use them-- like, including `<html>` and, critically `</html>`

So, now we've got a custom field with a description containing a `</html>` tag, and as you might expect, the browser is not showing anything past that last tag, including any option to delete or edit the field.

Is there any way to use an API, etc to delete this field or change its description?

I'm on JIRA 4.1.2 (I know...)

Comment: You can use the REST API to [update an issue](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis). This API is available in 5 or later, but you might be able to get at [the alpha version in 4.1.2](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/63385/does-rest-api-works-for-jira-version-4-1-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue...

- I used either the JIRA Advanced search, or right-click>>Inspect
  element to get the ID of the field.
- Then hovered over one of the "Configure" links that were showing to get the URL to the configure screen.
- Then, I put the correct ID in the URL, and I was able to get back in and remove the offending tags.

That resolved the issue on the Custom Fields screen. Unfortunately, this technique had also been used on the "Field Configuration" screen, which is organized a bit differently.

The URLs to the "Edit" screens from the field configuration are formatted differently, with `id=` being the particular field configuration you're working with (don't change this one), and `position=` being the position in the list of the field you're working with (0 based index).

The easiest thing for me was to

- Go to the field *above* the one that was messed up
- Click on the Edit link, then
- Increment the position parameter in the URL to give me the field I actually needed to change.

Deleted out the rogue HTML and everything was back to normal.